# Openlayer KML file

Tags: syntax, openlayers, kml

The following code is from a tutorial I have been following. But I am finding in the console there is a `UncaughtSyntaxError` after `new ol.layer.Vector({`

The following is the code:

```
//KML Layer
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.KML({
        extractStyles: false,
        projection:new ol.proj.get("EPSG:900913"),
        url:'js/test.kml'
    })
});
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

I just can't seem to see what's missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The API has changed. Try this instead.

```
var sourceVector = new ol.source.Vector({
      url: 'js/test.kml',
      format: new ol.format.KML()
    });
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({source: sourceVector });

map.addLayer(vector);
```